# Can CSS attributes change depending on the viewers proximity to different page anchors

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way of changing a CSS attribute, depending where on the page someone is?

I have **menu items** that link to **anchors** on the *same* page.

I want menu items to highlight (i.e. current) depending which anchor the viewer is nearest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Add an onscroll event to body and depending how much user scrolled (you can get scroll position -> document.documentElement.scrollTop) change the css.